# How can I stop a service with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have 30 servers that have a service called $servicename1 and want to stop that service on all 30 servers at once without waiting until the first one goes down first and then tries the second!

```
$servicename = "support_Cosmic"
$using= $serviceName


foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
#   Skriv ut status på tjänsten i passande färg.

    $getservicestatus = (Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus -eq "Running") {

      $jobs = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist { Stop-Service $using:serviceName }  -AsJob
      $jobs |Wait-Job |Receive-Job

      Write-Host "$server $servicename Stoppad!" -ForegroundColor Green
      }
    else
      {
      Write-Host "$server $servicename var redan Stopped!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Stop-Service` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service) instead of `Set-Service`:

```
Stop-Service -Name $servicename1 -ComputerName $server
```

If you want to run the code simultaneously on all the remote hosts, consider using `Invoke-Command -AsJob`:

```
$servicename = "support_Cosmic"
$serverlist = 'computer01','computer02' # etc.

$jobs = Invoke-Command { Stop-Service $using:serviceName } -ComputerName $serverlist -AsJob
$jobs |Wait-Job |Receive-Job
```

Comment: will it stop the service immediately and go to the next or wait until the service goes down properly first and then to the next?

Comment: `Stop-Service` won't return until the service has stopped or the attempt times out

Comment: I want to stop the service at once on all servers and not wait until it goes down properly!

Comment: Yes, I have 30 servers that have a service called $ servicename1 and want to stop that service on all 30 servers at once without waiting until the first one goes down first and then tries the second!

Comment: what is the $using ?    is it $using= $serviceName  ?

Comment: @amirbahoori the `using:` prefix copies the value of a local variable into a remote script block - so when `Stop-Service` executes on the remote machines, `$using:servicename1` will resolve to whatever value you've assigned to `$servicename1` locally

Comment: Can you write a complete script for example? should i have a separate script and then a script with invoke command? or can I have everything on a script?